# PHP: Keyword Searching: Find substring within a string

Tags: php, mysql

I am building a comics website and have implemented a search. The search originally used the image title... This worked fine:

```
if (strtolower($input)==strtolower(substr($row['title'],0,strlen($input)))) {
```

But now I feel that many people won't remember the title. So I've added a column to the database called "keywords", varchar [55]... and my test entry is the string "five, second, rule, food, rules". I figured I could replace `$row['title']` with `$row['keywords']` and the search would still work.

It worked if I start searching from the beginning of the string, like I enter "five, seco..." But not if I start from the middle of the string, like "second", or "rule", etc.

Any ideas on how I can make that work?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not use a MySQL `LIKE` query?

Comment: @MrCode, good idea, but then it won't help when searching for multiple keywords with the <i>wrong</i> order...i think

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The straightforward solution would be to use `stripos` instead:

```
if(stripos($input, $row['title']) !== false) {
    // row matches
}
```

However, this isn't really a good solution. It would be much better to offload the filtering to your database, so non-matching rows don't have to make the trip to your front end at all. If you keep keywords as a comma-separated field then [`LIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) or [`REGEXP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) would be a good choice of tool; if you normalized your database schema so that the 1-to-many relationship of comics to keywords is modeled with a separate `comic_keywords` table then matching would be even easier.

For example, assuming that `comic` has an `id` and `comic_keywords` has a `comic_id` and a `keyword`, you could select matching comics with

```
SELECT DISTINCT(comic_id) FROM comic_keywords WHERE keyword = 'blah'
```

Answer (score 7):

Doing it in a comic's column will only bring tears as it breaks normalization.  What you should do is make a keyword table that has one word per entry and then a pivot table that matches keywords to comics.  Then you can just do a join to find all the comics that match.

It's more work to setup, but more flexible in the long run.

EDIT:

Keyword table:

```
id     keyword
1      x-men
2      action
3      mystery
4      batman
etc.
```

comic_keyword table

```
comic_id    keyword_id
45          3
678         1
678         2
77          3
77          4
etc.
```

The second table (the pivot table) matches the ids of the comic to the ids of the keywords they're associated with.  That's how many-to-many relationships should be modeled in most cases.

Comment: Okay I may need an example if you have one

Comment: Oh okay, I gotcha. I'll have to spend some time trying to implement this.

Comment: Cool.  When you get it set up, run @Jon's `SELECT DISTINCT...` query on it.  It will remove all the duplicate entries, leaving you with individual titles.

Answer (score 1):

You can split the column on the fly:

```
if (in_array(strtolower($input), explode(', ', $row['title']))) {
  /* found it */
}
```

Comment: or even to build on this, use @mrcode 's idea of searchign `where keyword like %(<?php explode...?>)%`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html) or (less likely, but easier to set up) [MySQLs full-text search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html).

Comment: Yeah, Sphinx/Lucene/etc is always the easier solution to set up. [/sarcasm]